# Notepad++ regexp ID of the sub-expressions in the double parentheses

Tags: replace, expression, notepad++

I am trying to find in the Notepad++ strings like this:

```
'<a href="/mp3files/cards/Sentence With any Number of Words.mp3"></a>',
```

And convert them into this:

```
'<a href="/mp3files/cards/sentence-with-any-number-of-words.mp3"></a>',
```

I've made a regular expression to crop the string beginning with `cards/` and ending with `</a>`:

```
(cards/)([^\s]{1,50})(([\s\.\?\!\-\,])(\w{1,50}))+(\.mp3"></a>)
```

Or an alternative approach:

```
(cards/)([^\s]{1,50})([\s\.\?\!\-\,]{0,})([^\s]{1,50})
```

Both work fine for search, but I can't get the replacement.
The problem is that the number of words in a sentence may vary.
And I can't get the ID of sub-expressions in the double parentheses.

The following format of replacement: `\1\2\3...` doesn't work, as I can't get the correct ID of the sub-expressions in the double parentheses.
I tried to google the topic, but couldn't find anything. Any advice, link or best of all a full replacement expression will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that easy, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace all spaces after `/cards/` with a hyphen and lowercase the filename.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:href="/mp3files/cards/|\G)\K(?!\.mp3)(\S+)(?:\h+|(\.mp3))`
- Replace with: `\L$1(?2$2:-)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group
    href="/mp3files/cards/  # literally
  |                       # OR
    \G                      # restart fro last match position
)                       # end group
(?!\.mp3)               # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't ".mp3" after this position
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
(\S+)                   # group 1, 1 or more non spaces
(?:                     # non capture group
    \h+                     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  |                       # OR
    (\.mp3)                 # group 2, literally ".mp3"
)                       # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
\L$1            # lowercase content of group 1
(?2             # if group 2 exists (the extension .mp3)
    $2              # use it
  :               # else
    -               # put a hyphen
)               # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, Toto (upvoted). And would you be so kind to add the change to lowercase in the replacement?

Comment: @Ken: It's a bit more complex, see my edit.

Comment: Toto, thanks a lot. That was really helpful and educative for me.